# SVG clipping stroke on open paths

Tags: javascript, html, svg, clip

I'm trying to generate a path as the result of two others in which one acts as a *hard clipping path*. My goal is to achieve the effect of a shape being clipped by another one (I'm trying to make a web application with a simple visualizer for amplitude modulation on signals).

Here's a visual representation:

[image: amplitude modulation example]

For each case, the first path would be the *carrier* signal and the second one would be the *modulator*. The modulation operation is represented by the * operator; this means that the modulator shape limits the carrier: any segment/value outside of the modulator is cut to match the modulator shape.

A rough pseudocode implementation of this could be:

```
# assuming both shapes as same-length arrays of Y values 
# (minimum 0), and their indexes as X values
carrier = [...]
modulator = [...]
result = []

for each x from 0 to carrier.length:
  result.push(min(carrier[x], modulator[x]))

draw(result)
```

Since I have several paths to choose from for each operand, I want to avoid writing SVG paths for all of the possible combinations and aim for generating them on the fly instead. [Other answers related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193276/how-can-i-merge-two-shapes-in-svg) only work with closed/filled shapes and would only result in the shapes being intercepted. I also stumbled upon [Warp.js](https://benjamminf.github.io/warpjs/) but it's not exactly what I need since the transformation function given to it would affect the entire shape.

Some examples of the shapes I'm working with:

First pair of shapes:

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 70 70" width="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path
    d="M0,50 C0,50 0,0 25,0 L25,50 L50,50"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="2"
    fill="none"
  />
</svg>
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 70 70" width="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path
    d="M0,50 L0,0 L50,50"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="2"
    fill="none"
  />
</svg>
```

Last shape (third one is the same as the second one):

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 70 70" width="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http:/ /www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path
    d="M0,50 L25,0 L25,50 L50,0 L50,50"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="2"
    fill="none"
  />
</svg>
```

I'm not limited by any framework, so pure DOM manipulation is completely okay. Is there any way to achieve this just by using markup? or any other process that would yield the clipped path?

Comment: That's very unclear what the logical operator is to "mix" these shapes into that result. Could you try to define it at least in pseudo-code or even with words? is it like "The outline of the intersection of both shapes" (as if they were filled, but we keep only the "upper" stroke)?

Comment: @Kaiido Just added a couple more words and a rough pseudocode for it. I need the second outline to limit the first one, it should cut anything outside its limits. [This is another way to see it.](http://www.physics-and-radio-electronics.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/amplitudemodulation.png) I'm only trying to replicate this effect with the upper half of the waveform.

Comment: So this isn't really "clipping". It's more like a quite complex composite operation. I think I got it with the canvas API (and a little help from a CanvasLayer prototype of mine): https://jsfiddle.net/L365egvj/ I guess SVG <filter> could do that, though I didn't find an easy way to reference a <path> as `in2` in there. And given the number of layers this composition implies I guess that won't be simple to do.

Comment: And actually even my example fails with the first shape, it doesn't render the left most horizontal segment. Here is a dirty fix using some hard-coded values: https://jsfiddle.net/L365egvj/1/

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I also tried going through the filter way and found it would be tricky to get it done that way as well. Your CanvasLayer (great work btw) approach looks promising, although I see there's some horizontal segment that gets cut as well (maybe a rounding error?). Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about this by writing a new path, computing the path `d` attribute with Javascript. This is much too complex to provide a complete solution right here. But I think there are a number of hints that can get you in the right direction.

The main problem, as I see it, seems to be identifying the intersection points between two paths. Paths are made up of multiple segments, which can take quite a number of forms: lines, elliptical arcs, quadratic or cubic beziers, and they all can be expressed in multiple forms in the SVG path microsyntax. This makes a lot of cases to consider.

It's clearly a case for the use of a library that has already done the heavy lifting involved. There is the node.js library [path-intersection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-intersection), which is basically an excerpt from Adobe's [Snap.js](http://snapsvg.io/). Assuming the [API](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.intersection) is the same as the original, you'll be able to get a number of informations you will need to proceed.

What I haven't seen on first glance is whether this cleanly handles path segments that are continuously identical over some length, instead of intersecting just in a finite number of points. Ignoring this special case for now, a possible algorithm could have a rough outline like this:

- Make a list of all the intersecting points along the two paths.
- The library will identify the path segments where the intersection occurs, convert them to cubic beziers, and give you the coordinates of its four control points, and the corresponding `t` value.
- `t` is a variable between 0 and 1 that can be used to compute points along a bezier curve. For example the [`.get(t)`](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/#get) function from pomax' [Bezier.js](https://github.com/Pomax/bezierjs) library implements this.
- If you change the `t` values for both path segments for a small amount (any value that is not beyond the next intersection point), you will be able to identify which of the two paths has the lower `y` values in each direction from the intersection point.
- [Split](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/#split) the two path segments at `t` and exchange the original segment of your path for the two parts.
- Now you have two paths where each intersection point is also a segment edge, and you know for each which segment is the lower one. You can now write a path that is made up of all the lower segments.

The last two steps will obviously be easiest if you have a full [AST representation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-path-parser) of the path, but *may* also be doable with some Regexes.

Finally, all the libraries I mentioned do not need the DOM but only work on the path data. That's actually a good thing performance-wise and gives you more choices where to execute that code (for example on a server or in a Web Worker).

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! I haven't thought the path intersection library could yield bezier curves as well. Given that the intersections will always come in pairs (save for the overlapping horizontal/vertical segments) I would only have to split the paths and join them using straight lines as the modulator shapes I'm dealing with won't include curved segments at all.

Comment: But your first example _has_ a bezier in the resulting path...?

Comment: Yes, the first segment is indeed a bezier curve. I was noting the fact that the intercept library would help me get a point in terms of `t` instead of x,y which I could use for the split operation while using Bezier.js