# HTML Canvas - Draw stroke only on outside of overlapping semi-transparent arcs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw 2 semi-transparent circles with a stroke *only on the outside of the formed shape* on an HTML canvas with the following code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Canvas Arcs</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    // Get the canvas element and its context
    const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';
    
    context.arc(100, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.arc(200, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    
    context.stroke()
    context.fill();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue I have with the result is that the stroke is being drawn on each arc separately as well as that parallel line that I assume "closes the path".

[image: The two circles with unintended stroke]

The desired result would look something like the image below. I am able to achieve this result with the fill being a solid color instead of semi-transparent. However, in my actual application, the fill needs to be semi-transparent to reveal other elements that are below the drawn shape.

[image: The two circles with stroke only on outside of the shape]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge two shapes in svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193276/how-can-i-merge-two-shapes-in-svg)

Comment: Can you provide an image about hows the result needs to looks like ?

Comment: @TaigeWang don't think so... i am going to be drawing the shapes dynamically on the canvas with JavaScript.

Comment: @PabloSalazar Added an image in the original question.

Comment: works for you if we add the same color of the canva to the border ?

Answer (score 0):

I try to solve it base on the desired result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Canvas Arcs</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif");
    }

 
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>

  <script>
    // Get the canvas element and its context
    const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)';
    context.strokeStyle = `hsla(0, 100%, 50%, 0.0)`;
    
    context.arc(100, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.arc(200, 100, 80, 0, Math.PI * 2);

    context.stroke()
    context.fill();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont think this works because in this case the stroke is just transparent. The hsla used in the strokeStyle has alpha value at 0. If we were to set that to 1, the stroke would show the same way as in my question.